# Require type A is a string in type B array in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a type that looks like this:

```
type MyType = {
  tabs: string[];
  activeTab: string;
}
```

I want to require that `activeTab` is a member of `tabs`.  Is there a way to do this with generics?

Comment: There are ways of using generics to help you here, but it would be helpful if you showed some use cases to make this a [mre].  Like, [this](https://tsplay.dev/N53rPW) is one way to proceed, but of course it has caveats.   Does that work for you?  If not, please [edit] the question to demonstrate missing use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure can. Just accept a generic parameter that is a union of all possible strings.

```
type MyType<Tab extends string> = {
  tabs: Tab[];
  activeTab: Tab;
}

const a: MyType<'asd' | 'qwe'> = {
  tabs: ['asd', 'qwe'],
  activeTab: 'asd'
}

const b: MyType<'asd' | 'qwe'> = {
  tabs: ['asd', 'qwe'],
  activeTab: 'nope' // Type '"nope"' is not assignable to type '"asd" | "qwe"'
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.5.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq4IB54EMBGUIA9gQDsATAZyhOACcBLAgcwD4oBeKAbwCgophMSAuKOgwBtALoBuLlDQBjYNQBuEYYOFSAvhw6yA9gQozBcRJGQByNCSLmoAHyjmAjgHcI5pq07deGAVBFLa3MAGkdXdzEQ6TkFZVVHKxsOLR19QwxjBCQLJNsHZzcPFnZpX39AvLDCyOjuWKUVTEFzAl1IWwB6TqEkRwAiNsh+22oyNuAZEhJqOgJMABtoYF0ePvN+pP77KH6IkZSgA)

Comment: Of course `const c: MyType<'asd' | 'qwe'> = {tabs: [], activeTab: 'asd'}` is also accepted here.  Depending on the use case this could be no problem, or it could be catastrophic.  Hoping the OP will add some use cases to the example code.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if it would be nice to have "constrained by X but X is not allowed" feature in Typescript that would force you to use any valid _subtype_. I'm not convinced it's for sure a win of a feature, but still, I wonder.

Comment: or just use the little conditional from this answer of yours @jcalz https://tsplay.dev/N53rPW, it's cute. :p I guess I didn't realize you could use `T` on both sides of the conditional there.